# ¿como saco los datos sin duplicar de un arraylist?

Tags: java

Tengo un list de arrays, uno de esos arrays tiene cosas repetidas y debo cargarlas en otro sitio. Entonce la pregunta es como saco los datos no repetidos de ese array que hay dentro de un arraylist para poder mostrarlos en otro sitio. Tengo esto

```
 public void inicializarMedicos() {
        int[] idsD = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        String[] nombres = {"Elena Díaz López", "Juan Ruiz Luque", "Marta Jaén García", "Ana Pérez Martín",
            "José Guerrero Castro"};
        int[] comsultas = {1, 3, 2, 4, 5};
        String[] especialidad = {"Medicina General", "Medicina General", "Pediatría", "Pediatría", "Cirugía"};
        Doctor nuevoDoctor;
        for (int i = 0; i < idsD.length; i++) {
            nuevoDoctor = new Doctor(idsD[i], nombres[i], especialidad[i], comsultas[i], listaCitas);
            listaDoctores.add(nuevoDoctor);
            cargaListaMedicos();
        }
    }
```

Como veis lista doctores tiene ids, nombre, especialidad ... Entonces necesito sacar las especialidades sin repetir para cargar un Jcombobox (no viene acuento). Lo importante es sacar los datos y meterlos en otro arraylist o en otro sitio sin vovler a meterlos a mano obviamete.
Es obligatorio sacarlo de la lista de doctores y no del array de especialidades,.

Admito cambios en el codigo osea los String[] puedo cambiarlo a list si es mas sencillo

Clase doctor

```
public static int codigo = 1;
    public String nombreDoctor;
    public String especialidad;
    public int numConsulta;
    public List<Cita> listaCitas;

    public Doctor(int codigo, String especialidad, String nombreDoctor, int numConsulta, List<Cita> listaCitas) {
        Doctor.codigo = codigo;
        this.nombreDoctor = nombreDoctor;
        this.especialidad = especialidad;
        this.numConsulta = numConsulta;
        this.listaCitas = listaCitas;

    }

    public Doctor(List<Cita> listaCitas) {
        codigo = Doctor.codigo++;
        this.listaCitas = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public int getNumConsulta() {
        return numConsulta;
    }

    public void setNumConsulta(int numConsulta) {
        this.numConsulta = numConsulta;
    }

    public static int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public static void setCodigo(int codigo) {
        Doctor.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getEspecialidad() {
        return especialidad;
    }

    public void setEspecialidad(String especialidad) {
        this.especialidad = especialidad;
    }

    public String getNombreDoctor() {
        return nombreDoctor;
    }

    public void setNombreDoctor(String nombreDoctor) {
        this.nombreDoctor = nombreDoctor;
    }

    public List<Cita> getListaCitas() {
        return listaCitas;
    }

    public void setListaCitas(List<Cita> listaCitas) {
        this.listaCitas = listaCitas;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma correcta finalmente para que funcione a sido esta :

```
 Set<String> especialidadesSinRepetir = new HashSet<>();
        for (int x = 0; x < listaDoctores.size(); x++) {
            especialidadesSinRepetir.add(listaDoctores.get(x).getEspecialidad());
        }

        for (String especialidad : especialidadesSinRepetir) {

            cmbEspecialidad.addItem(especialidad);
        }
    }
```

no podia usar LinkedHashSet por ser una matriz y luego no poder meterla en el boton facilmente

Answer (score 1):

**Remover duplicados con LinkedHashSet**

Imports:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
```

Código:

```
List<String> listaEspecialidadesAux = new ArrayList();
for(int x=0;x<listaDoctores.size();x++){
    listaEspecialidadesAux.add(listaDoctores.get(x).getEspecialidad());
}
LinkedHashSet<String> linkedHashSet = new LinkedHashSet<>(listaEspecialidadesAux);

String[] especialidadWithoutDuplicates = linkedHashSet.toArray(new String[] {});
```

---

[Array remove duplicate elements](https://howtodoinjava.com/array/array-remove-duplicate-elements/)

Comment: El problema es que necesito sacar lso datos del  arraylist de arrays osea de listadeDoctores no del String[]

Comment: @unknow Itera en el arraylist y create un array/arraylist auxiliar solo con las especialidades de esos doctores, y después quitas los duplicados

Comment: Y como hago eso yo se recorrer un arraylist normal pero un arraylist de arrays ya me pierdo

Comment: @unknow Tienes un arraylist de objetos , en este caso de tipo `Doctor`, no conozco los getters, pero bueno, edito la pregunta para que te hagas una idea.

Comment: te lo pongo edito la pregunta

Comment: Me lo había supuesto que era `.getEspecialidad()` de todas maneras no hacia falta. Con lo te he puesto en la respuesta te debería de funcionar!

Comment: no etniendo porque volver a poner String[] especialidad = {"Medicina General", "Medicina General", "Pediatría", "Pediatría", "Cirugía"}; la idea es sacar dicho array directamente de lista de doctores sin volver a ponerlo.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100532/discussion-between-x3k-js-and-unknow).

Comment: @unknow He editado la respuesta, si necesitas otra cosa por favor pregunta en el chat que se ha creado.